# How to use specific font styles with CSS, from Google fonts (ie. thin, extra-light..)

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-webfonts

Google served font like [Montserrat](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat?selection.family=Montserrat) has a lot of different styles:
Thin, Extra-Light, Light, Regular, etc...

I could not find a way to specify a style with CSS.
Using Font-weight can access only some of them as can be seen in this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/is_this_taken/pen/ryxOwa)

```
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:thin,extra-light,light,100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800' 
rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

`<p class="w100">This is 100 weight</p>`

```
body {
 padding: 0 20px;
 font-family: 'Montserrat';
 font-size:40px;
}

.w100 {
 font-weight: 100;
}
```

I want to use the Extra-Light style, but regular is the lightest I get.

Is there a straight forward solution to this?

Update:
It was a browser problem. My Chrome has issues with fonts. The code i posted works just fine.

Comment: It says `hin` instead of `thin` in your first line. But you can remove that anyway - `100` is sufficient. And `100` is also the lightest. If that doesn't work for you, you'll need to look for a different font I guess.

Comment: Fixed the typos, same result.

Comment: Looking at source of the Google font page they are using @font-face definition for every weight, which I want to avoid as I'd have to link to the specific font files. The links could possibly change in the future breaking stuff.

Answer (score 32):

The Google fonts page will actually tell you how to do it and includes a weight select utility. If you want the thinnest style, this is it for *Montserrat* (different fonts have different weights available):

HTML:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:100" rel="stylesheet">
```

Compare that to yours, it has redundant weights and two errors (`href='//` instead of `href="https://` and `hin` instead of `thin`)

CSS:

```
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-weight: 100;
```

If you want additional weights, add them like this:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:100,200,300" rel="stylesheet">
```

Remember that you only want to specify those that you are actually going to use, as they will need to be downloaded, hence increasing your page's load time.

Here is a working example for *Montserrat*. If `100` isn't thin enough for you, you're out of luck.

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.w100 {
  font-weight: 100;
}
.w200 {
  font-weight: 200;
}
.w300 {
  font-weight: 300;
}
.w400 {
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:100,200,300,400" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p class="w100">This is 100 weight</p>
    <p class="w200">This is 200 weight</p>
    <p class="w300">This is 300 weight</p>
    <p class="w400">This is 400 weight</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Presuming, of course, the additional weights are available.

Comment: I fixed the typos, but the result is the same. You can compare my CodePen example or your code with the Google Font page you will see the difference.

Comment: @is_this_taken Actually, it looks fine/same to me: http://imgur.com/a/0xCME Maybe an issue with your browser?

Comment: Wow, thanks, it seems to be a browser issue. Chrome is having issues. In Firefox it's working fine.

Answer (score 5):

After importing the font link from google fonts in your index.html. Create a global.css file consisting css code of Montserrat font family with different font weights.

I'm using this font in my react project.

import or link font from google fonts. Mine looks like this

```
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');
      </style>
```

It's very useful for you to go through the css file to use each variant in font family.

```
   .thin {
        /* Montserrat Thin = 100 */
        font-weight: 100;
        font-family: Montserrat, "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    
    .extralight {
        /* Montserrat Extra Light = 200 */
        font-weight: 200;
        font-family: Montserrat, "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    
    
    .light {
        /* Montserrat Light = 300 */
        font-weight: 300;
        font-family: Montserrat, "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    
    
    .regular {
        /* Montserrat Regular = 400 */
        font-weight: 400;
        font-family: Montserrat, "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    
    
    .medium {
        /* Montserrat Medium = 500 */
        font-weight: 500;
        font-family: Montserrat, "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    
    
    .semibold {
        /* Montserrat Semi-bold = 600 */
        font-weight: 600;
        font-family: Montserrat, "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    
    
    .bold {
        /* Montserrat Bold = 700 */
        font-weight: 700;
        font-family: Montserrat, "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    
    
    .extrabold {
        /* Montserrat Extra Bold = 800 */
        font-weight: 800;
        font-family: Montserrat, "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    
    
    .black {
        /* Montserrat Black = 900 */
        font-weight: 900;
        font-family: Montserrat, "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
```