# How to get black font weight from a Google font

Tags: css, fonts

Please go [here](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat) end see `Black` font style.  How do I get this style on my page. Here is what I've tried so far, but it's not working.

```css
.title{
font-family:'montserrat' sans-serif;
font-weight:900;
font-weight:Black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">

<div class='title'>LOREM</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the `font-family` property requires values to be separated by a comma. Also, you should use the capital letter in the value.

Therefore, this…

```css
font-family: 'montserrat' sans-serif;
```

…should be

```css
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
```

[image]

To add more weights to your font, use the customize menu:

[image]

Then, simply add the corresponding `font-weight` or `font-style` value:

```css
font-weight: 900;
```

If you don't have that weight specified in your generated `<link>`, then the fallback family and weight will be used.

Answer (score 1):

There are several variants based on which you can import the fonts. For Montserrat, there are Regular 400, Bold 700, Black 900 and many more. Just select the variant type and add that font, now you are good to go.

Based on your question the URL you need is

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:900" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: write it this way for your CSS
font-family: 'Montserrat', 'sans-serif';

Answer (score 1):

First use `'Montserrat', sans-serif;` (with `,`)

Second  `font-weight:black;` is invalid so remove it...

You can use `font-style:normal`

```css
.title{
font-family:'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-weight:900;
font-style:normal;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:900" rel="stylesheet">

<div class='title'>black</div>
```

Comment: that's not `black` font weight

Comment: try this link:`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:900" rel="stylesheet">` :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42532511/how-to-use-specific-font-styles-with-css-from-google-fonts-ie-thin-extra-lig

Comment: see here how black looks like:https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/montserrat